# После установки Lodash сломался проект

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Работаю в Visual Studio.
Установил npm i lodash@4.17.15 после чего стала подчеркиваться ошибка над импортом проекта и повылазило куча ошибок везде.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске проекта npm start выдает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто сможет подсказать, что делать?

Comment: Начать можно как советуют - с запуска npn audit fix. Или npn audit fix --force. Бывает так, что это устраняет проблемы. Или уменьшает их количество...

Comment: @ksa Спасибо. Помогло. Я сначала ввел первую команду  npm audit fix потом вторую npm audit fix --force. ошибки исправились.